# Regex Phone Number Using Validation V2 Golang Package Not Working

Tags: regex, go

I am having some trouble when using `github.com/go-validator/validator` to validate regex some phone numbers with this prefix +62, 62, 0, for instance number e.g. +628112blabla, 0822blablabla, 628796blablabla.

I have try my regex on [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/qtEg6H/9) and no issue with the regex on that. Here the regex is :

```
(0|\+62|062|62)[0-9]+$
```

But when I try with my go implement with it, the regex not working. This is my code for implement the purpose :

```
type ParamRequest struct {
    PhoneNumber string `validate:"nonzero,regexp=(0|\+62|062|62)[0-9]+$"`
    ItemCode    string `validate:"nonzero"`
    CallbackUrl string `validate:"nonzero"`
}

func (c *TopupAlloperatorApiController) Post() {
    var v models.TopupAlloperatorApi

    interf := make(map[string]interface{})

    json.Unmarshal(c.Ctx.Input.RequestBody, &interf)

    logs.Debug(" Json Input Request ", interf)
    var phone, item, callback string

    if _, a := interf["PhoneNumber"].(string); a {
        phone = interf["PhoneNumber"].(string)
    }
    if _, b := interf["ItemCode"].(string); b {
        item = interf["ItemCode"].(string)
    }

    if _, c := interf["CallbackUrl"].(string); c {
        callback = interf["CallbackUrl"].(string)
    }

    ve := ParamRequest{
        PhoneNumber: phone,
        ItemCode:    item,
        CallbackUrl: callback,
    }

    logs.Debug(" Param Request ", ve)



    err := validator.Validate(ve)
    if err == nil {
       //success
    }else{
      // not success
    }
```

Many thanks for anything help. Thank you.

Comment: I believe you actually want to use `^` to anchor the match at the start of the string, too: `^(0|\+62|062|62)[0-9]+$`. What do you mean by it does not work?

Comment: I have tried using ^ too, but still the same. I have using ^ for the first time until I get online tester link for validate my regex. It's does'nt work properly on my golang code. It's like skip all the validations, but if I delete the regex validation, all validation (nonzero validation) working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using regexp to check `PhoneNumber` that won't be matching if the value is empty it is better to remove `nonzero` from the validation.
I have checked out documentation and haven't found examples where you can use both: `nonzero` and `regexp`.
Also you need to make your regex symbol-escaped, otherwise it won't be detected by reflection. It means you should use `(0|\\+62|062|62)[0-9]+$` in your code. Here is example where problem is: [symbol escaping in struct tags](https://play.golang.org/p/h0xIzZiXpP)
And also, please try to use this regexp: `^\\+{0,1}0{0,1}62[0-9]+$`

Comment: Great.. Thanks. It's working now.  It's all about symbol escaping in struct tags. I am using `(0|\\+62|062|62)[0-9]+$` and also with nonzero validate too.

`type ParamRequest struct {
 PhoneNumber string `validate:"nonzero,regexp=^(0|\\+62|062|62)[0-9]+$"`
 ItemCode    string `validate:"nonzero"`
}`

 Thanks